# Connecting to Google SMTP with Konica Minolta Printers

Tags: gmail, smtp, multi-function-printer

I have spent the better portion of two days trying to get a number of Bizhub MFCs to connect to Google's SMTP service.  Our company recently switched from an exchange server, which handled SMTP requests to Gmail.  We have 20 branches each with different MFCs.  I was able to get the Cannons connected, but the Konicas are giving me major problems.

The three models that are giving me issues are the C203, C250 and the C280.

I have used the following:

```
smtp.gmail.com
port 465
Gmail Username/Pass

aspmx.l.google.com
port 25
no authentication

aspmx.l.google.com
port 25
Gmail Username/Pass
```

None of these methods are working despite the fact that all of those have worked on different makes/models.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm at my whit's end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!

I needed to add an SPF TXT record to my DNS settings.  The machines which were able to use SSL to send to smtp.gmail.com were working fine because they do not require the record.  However, any of the printers which didn't allow SSL needed this record to connect with aspmx.l.google.com.

I initially thought the record already existed because some of them are working, but upon further inspection, I was incorrect.

For reference:
To create an SPF record for a domain: [Creating Google SPF Records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178723)

> Log in to the administrative console for your domain. Locate the page
>   from which you can update the DNS records. You may need to enable
>   advanced settings. Create a TXT record containing this text: v=spf1
>   include:_spf.google.com ~all
>
> Publishing an SPF record that uses -all instead of ~all may result in
>   delivery problems. See Google IP address ranges for details about the
>   addresses for the Google Apps mail servers. If your registrar also
>   requires a host setting (such as @), see the TXT records for specific
>   domain providers list for precise instructions. Save your changes.
>   Keep in mind that changes to DNS records may take up to 48 hours to
>   propagate throughout the Internet. If you have difficulty creating an
>   SPF record, contact your domain provider for assistance.